# multiple messages are recieved on content page when just one is sent?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

when i send on message even then four times the alert is triggering !
don't know what is wrong !
I am adding the manifest too.

background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method == "123")
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "xyz"});
            })  
    }
});
```

content.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request) {
        alert(request.method);
        if (request.method == "xyz"){   
            alert("hello);
         }
});
```

this is the the manifest file
manifest :

```
{
"manifest_version" : 2,
"version" : "0.1.0.0",
"name" : "xyz",
  "short_name": "xyz",
    "permissions" : ["    <all_urls>","tabs","storage","notifications","unlimitedStorage","downloads"],  

"background": {
 "scripts": ["background.js"]

  },

 "content_scripts": [{

"matches": ["<all_urls>","http://*/*","https://*/*"], 
"js": [
    "content.js",
      ],
   "all_frames" : true
 }],
"browser_action" : {
    "default_title" : "test",
    "default_popup" : "popup.html"
},
"devtools_page" : "xyz.html" 

}
```

Comment: Where did you send your message at first?

Comment: I am sending the message from devtool panel to background then from background to content !

Comment: could you please provide more codes like your `manifest.json`? I guess you also inject your script for iframes.

Comment: added the manifest !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared `"all_frames": true` in your `manifest.json`, which means your content scripts will be injected into every iframe in your webpage, then when message is sent from background page, every listener in content script will respond to that.

To solve this,

1. Remove `"all_frames"` part or set it `false`
2. If you do want you scripts to be injected into frames and only want to respond to message in top window, you could detect the content script by checking `window !== window.top`

   ```
   if (window !== window.top) {
       chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(callback);
   }
   ```
3. Or exclude the iframes when sending the message:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "xyz"}, {frameId: 0});
   ```

Comment: hey sorry mate but by all frames what do you mean ? if i remove it then the content script still will be acting on the current webpage ?

Comment: @Ram, of course, all_frames controls whether the content script runs in all frames of the matching page, or only the top frame.

Comment: ok ok ! so if it is removed even then content script will have access to the whole web page ?