# chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener Receive repeatedly by iframe

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener Receive repeatedly by iframe

```
/// background.js
(function () {
    function toggle(tab) {
        console.log('activate:', tab.url, tab.id);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: 'hihi'});
     }

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(toggle);
}());


//contents.js
(function () {
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, 
    sendResponse) {
        console.log('call : ', request.action);
    });
    return true;
})();

// manifest.json
"all_frames": true 

// console result
call :  hihi
call :  hihi
call :  hihi
```

- "all_frames": true, an instance runs in each frame/iframe of the page and each one gets the message.
- Can I know that which iframe is received?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple messages are recieved on content page when just one is sent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857806/multiple-messages-are-recieved-on-content-page-when-just-one-is-sent)

Comment: "Can I know that which iframe is received" - depends on what you mean by "know". The code already "knows" simply because it receives it. You can add `document.body` in your console.log so it'll be highlighted on mouseover, and you can navigate to the DOM tree by right-clicking it.